# Cross site, same domain cookie confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one site that is done in asp.net.  And another newer site that is done in asp.net MVC, LINQ and Razor.

When I visit the old site oldsite/default?userid=243 this sets cookies and session variables.  When I visit the new site oldsite:88 I open up my cookie viewer and it appears the cookies are still set.

I am now trying to test this on the new site by writing out the values of the cookies.

I have tried this code:

```
@{ 
if (!(Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value == "")) 
{
    <span>Cookie: @Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value</span>
}
if (!(Session["UserID"].ToString() == ""))
{
    <span>Session: @Session["UserID"].ToString()</span>
}
}
```

But the page errors out and the page is live (as I can't use my local host because the domains would be different and thus the cookies not transferred.

How do I tell me new site that if this cookie doesn't exist just move along.  Otherwise if it does exist then write out the value of it.  I'm not having much luck right now.

The reason I need to check if it exist is because not everyone will be using the new site through the old site.  some will be just accessing the new site and thus won't have or need cookies at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for null.  You're getting an error because you are trying to read the `Value` property of a cookie that doesn't exist.  You are probably seeing a `NullReferenceException`.

```
@{ 
if (Request.Cookies["UserID"] != null) 
{
    <span>Cookie: @Request.Cookies["UserID"].Value</span>
}
}
```

---

By the way, to set up your dev environment to share cookies with another environment, modify your hosts file and map a subdirectory of your domain:

c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 dev.mydomain.com
```

And add a binding to that domain in your local IIS.

Now, when you browse to dev.mydomain.com, you will load your localhost site, but with the security restrictions of a sub domain, which means you can share cookies.

Comment: Thank you on both accounts, I will modify my host file so I can stop messing up the live version.  :)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to check if cookie name is present before accessing value: instead of using indexing which will either give you "key not found" or `null` value for missing values check if `Cookies.AllKeys` contains key you are interested in.

MSDN links [Request.Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx) (with sample of using AllKeys) and [HttpCookieCollection.AllKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookiecollection.allkeys.aspx)

```
if(Request.Cookies.AllKeys
    .Contains("UserID", StrngComparer.StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))...
```